# Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Je souhaite faire une slash command pour un bot discord, ces dernière fonctionnaient très bien depuis un moment depuis aujourd'hui, impossible de lancer une commande sans que le bot crash juste après. Je n'ai toucher à rien depuis.

```
const { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../../config');


class command {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "videoskip",
        this.description = "Changer le channel d'annonce vidéo (STAFF)"
    }

    async execute(bot, interaction) {
        if (interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)) {
        skipVideo = false;
        const SKIP = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setTitle('✅ **__Vidéo changé de destination__**')
            .setDescription("La prochaine vidéo est changé de destination (<#1023891712403312720> → <#748247106980020236>)")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({ text: config.clients.name, iconURL: config.clients.logo});

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [SKIP] });
        console.log("Une vidéo a été changé de destination")
    }

    else {
        const Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('Random')
        .setTitle('‍♂️ **Action de modération**')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: config.clients.name, iconURL: config.clients.logo})
        .setDescription("Tu n'as pas la permission d'éxécuter cette commande");
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Embed] });

        }
}
}
module.exports = command
```

Résultat de la console:

```
Un utilisateur à utilisé la commande /planning
planning.js:56
Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at DiscordAPIError (c:\Users\galax\Documents\GitHub\TwiZzyxBot-Discord-V2\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:186:5)
    at runRequest (c:\Users\galax\Documents\GitHub\TwiZzyxBot-Discord-V2\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
index.js:186
Process exited with code 1
```

I want to make sure that this error does not happen again because with the bot becomes unusable

Comment: Make sure you translate the first paragraph to English as well, otherwise your question will be closed soon.

Comment: Also, I don't think that's the file causing the error. The error message says the error is coming from `planning.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears when you have another instance of the bot running somewhere.

An example- you are hosting the bot on a third party service and are doing development on a local machine. One of the instances of the bot is acknowledging and sending Discord's servers a "receipt" of the interaction being acknowledged and so the "slower" bot gets the reply that you are getting. This can occur if you somehow have 2 instances of the bot on your local machine as well- one will run normally, the other will get this error

---

**There's a couple potential solutions here:**

1. Check to make sure you do not have 2 event handlers on for the "*interactionCreate*" event
2. Shut down/turn off the bot that is being hosted or running anywhere that *isn't* your development environment
3. Use a different token for your testing/development environment (i.e. create a new bot in the Discord Developer Portal solely for testing)

---

Hope this helps!